# retrieve data from database with column name "name_en-GB"

Tags: mysql

I have a table in my database I need to retrieve data from it all things works fine but i am having a column name as name_en-GB when i tried to retrieve the data from it, it is giving error

```
select * from table where name_en-GB='Name';
```

The error is:

```
Unknown column 'name_en' in 'where clause'
```

What i came to know is after "-" the data is escaping.I have searched for this but i could not get it.How can get data from this column
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using brackets `[name_en-GB]`

Comment: @Nadeem_MK MySQL, not MSSQL

Comment: Yep, confusion! Sorry dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Terrible column name but all you need to do is quote it as an identifier, eg

```
select * from table where `name_en-GB` = 'Name';
```

For more information, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html

Comment: sorry phil i have seen your response late but thanks for your response  it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

try to use

```
select * from table where `name_en-GB`='Name'
```

Answer (score -1):

You could change the name of the column to name_en_GB